Create a Sql Statement IN DBT macro and use the query in the dbt model
my_macro.sql
{macro my_macro(value)}

{% set query  %}

select A from value

{{ return(query) }}

{% endset %}

{% endmacro %}


model.sql
select * from B
where A in ({{ my_macro(value) }}

when i compile the code
I get the result as
output:
select * from B
Where A in (     )

I'm not getting the sql statement as output of the macro
I know that we can execute the query and get the results can we pass the query as string ?
Is this actually possible in DBT?.

You almost get it. Just three things:

Move {% endset %} before return
Change value in {{ value }}
Try to avoid hardcoding table references and use either source() or ref()

{macro my_macro(value)}

{% set query  %}

select A from {{ value }}

{% endset %}

{{ return(query) }}

{% endmacro %}


It worked -Thanks
